# Network adapter slow - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, lan, microcontroller

I'm having problems with my internet speed when connected to a PLC. 
I'm connected to the PLC with an ethernet cable and to the internet via WiFi. 
The LAN adapter has a static IP set but I don't get why it slows down the WiFi connection. 
I've tried using a USB LAN adapter but it makes no difference, so I'm thinking it might be an OS problem. I'm using Win 7 Home Premium SP1.

I doubt that the PLC itself is the problem.

If anyone had a similar problem I would very much appreciate any advice.

Cheers,
V.

Comment: So your WiFi slows down or has issues only when you connect to the PLC or is it any time you have the wired LAN connected?

Comment: Hi, it only slows down when I'm connected to the PLC. I'm thinking it might be due to the static IP address that I need to enter for the wired connection to the PLC, but I access the internet through WiFi and I don't set an IP address for the WiFi.

Comment: It sounds like you might just need to set your WiFi's NIC priority over your LAN's: https://levynewsnetwork.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/windows-7-default-internet-connection-choice/ ...

Comment: I did what you said and it seems to be working.
Thank you very much for the help.
Is there any way to upvote your comment or close the question?